# How to Transform XMLDocument to XLS using XSLT in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, excel, xslt

I am trying to Transform the XSLT,XSL file into .xsl . So i tried below coding

```
string MyXmlPath = ReportPath + @"\XML\chennai.xml";
dataset.WriteXml(MyXmlPath);
string MyExcelPath = ReportPath + @"\Report\chennai.xls";

XPathDocument xmlDoc = new XPathDocument(MyXmlPath);
XslCompiledTransform XSLTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
XSLTransform.Load(AppBasePath + @"\Master\XSLT\chennai.xslt");
XSLTransform.Transform(MyXmlPath, MyExcelPath);
```

Above Coding is working fine. **But when i open the created Excel sheet it is opening in XML SPREAD SHEET 2003. But it should be open in Excel 97-2003 Workbook. How can i achieve ?**

Comment: If you are transforming XML with XSLT, then you are almost certainly outputting Spreadsheet XML 2003. Is the issue you are actually having is that you are getting a warning message box shown when the file is opened to say it is in the incorrect format?

Comment: @TimC yes.It shows Chennai.xls is in a different format than specified by the file extension.